# IBM DB2 LPAD/RPAD

Tags: sql, db2

I use db2 v.9.1 on windows 2003 server so it can not use LPAD or RPAD functions scalar.
because that functions support only z/OS right?

Now, I use this way for pad zero when COLUMN1 type is VARCHAR

```
 RIGHT('0000' ||  COLUMN1 ,4) AS  RPAD
 LEFT('0000' ||  COLUMN1 ,4) AS  LPAD
```

Have better way for replace LPAD or RPAD function?

Comment: Shouldn't it be?

 LEFT(COLUMN1 || '0000' ,4) AS RPAD
RIGHT('0000' || COLUMN1 ,4) AS LPAD

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want the [REPEAT](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000842.htm) scalar function.

Answer (score 0):

```
REPEAT('0',4) || column_name
```

Now if you want to limit the 0 based on the number of characters you can use the `RIGHT` function and it would look something like this assuming your column is `varchar(10)`:

`RIGHT(REPEAT('0',4) || column_name, 10)` in this case if you have characters it will fill it with 4 preceding 0s but if you have 7 characters it would fill it with 3 0s.

So you would have:
00001,
000012,
0000123,
00001234,
000012345,
0000123456,
0001234567,
0012345678,
etc.